# Cell background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to got own background for every cell but it looks like:

[image: example cell image]

Here's the code I'm working with

```
cell.team1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.team2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.dateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.stadiumLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `UITableViewCell` class reference, there's a property called `backgroundView` that should be the thing you're looking for.

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"image"];
[cell setBackgroundView: background];
[background release];
```

There's a property called `selectedBackgroundView` as well, which is used instead of the regular one, when the cell is selected/highlighted.

EDIT: Just tried this code, at least it's working when the cell has one label inside of it. Not sure about multiple, but if you haven't added any other views to the cell it should work as intended.

Comment: By "any other views" I mean a container view that contains all the labels or something like that. If there are any of those, you should set their backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: One thing to be aware of is the potential performance penalties associated with transparent views used in tableview cells.  A quote from the docs: "if you do take this approach, avoid making the views transparent, if you can. Transparent subviews affect scrolling performance because of the increased compositing cost"  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15

Comment: It's not that bad in reality, but yes, using opaque images will be a better performance decision.

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage...
```

Comment: Nothing, but the background is now complete white.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorwithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"]];
```

Comment: Nothing, but the background is now complete white.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom cell then you can set your image in uiimageview in the cell itself. It will work as background image... :)